# Redirecting external URLs to an exit page

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

What would be the best way to redirect users who request an external URL, to a sort of good-bye page?

I know I could work hard to install some sort of mod_rewrite-like module. But can't I do some sort of Page_OnRequest type function in global.asax or the master pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use jQuery to hook the click event on all the  tags on the page:

```
$(function(){

  $('a').click(function(e){
    var proceed       = true ;
    var anchor        = $(this) ;
    var href          = anchor.attr('href') ;
    var isExternalUrl = CheckForExternalUrl( href ) ;

    if ( isExternalUrl )
    {
      e.PreventDefault() ;
      window.location = "outside_link.aspx?url=" + href ;
      proceed         = false ;
    }
    return proceed ;
  }) ;
}) ;
```

Any link that gets clicked fires the event handler. External URLs will cause the page outside_link.aspx to loaded with the destination url in the query string. Internal URLs will behave normally.

Simple.

Comment: I was thinking of this, except with dojo. but I am worried they may disable javascript or have noscript etc. Essentially though, this is probably better. Though I would prefer a server-side method.

Comment: The write an HttpModule that overrides EndRequest(). Or do it in global.asax's Application_EndRequest(). Have your implementation iterate over the Html and do the required link fixups for external links. See http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm.

Answer (score 5):

You could have these urls actually point to a redirection page on your own site before forwarding them on to the ultimate destination:

```
<a href="redirect.aspx?url=stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Then you could do whatever you wanted with the redirection, and it could be worked so that the redirection hid the url, encoded it, added parameters, etc.

Comment: It seems this is a pretty common practice.

Comment: @DashTechnical - It's not really one I engage in because it seems a bit too "big brotherish", but it is one that I've seen employed on several sites.

Comment: What about the situation in which all links are already written? Just find+replace?

Comment: Ideally I would think links of this nature would be coming out of some sort of content management system so they could be captured on the fly in a find/replace manner as you mention. This could be done in a number of areas. You could even override (in a page baseclass) the `Page_Render` event to catch these urls as they "go out the door".

Comment: :(... I wish this was as easy as with Apache, using mod_rewrite without trying to find third party apps.